# Cannot select a python interpreter in VScode

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code, interpreter, pythoninterpreter

I'm having some troubles trying to select a python interpreter in VScode.
As you can see in this picture ([VScode: select python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENwpp.png)), VScode asks me to select a python interpreter but when I click on it, it doesn't present me any options: [python interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dh7uS.png).

Along with this problem (and I believe that they are related), I cannot debug because I get this error messages: [cannot debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxuUD.png)

Did anyone experienced this issues?
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure you have Python installed in your system? If yes, where is it?

Comment: did you use Kite? probably VSCode is not able to detect it according to your Screenshot of "Cannot Debug"

Comment: You also need the python extension in VSCode it is by microsoft

Comment: @MatheusBruhnsBastos, I do have python installed but I reinstalled it just to be sure.

Comment: @AdityaVartak, I don't have kite installed and I never had. This functionality stopped working 2 days ago but I already used it. I was using the debug functionality very often and, 2 days ago, it simply stopped.

Comment: @SubhashR, I have the extension installed.